# Center align only the selected line-Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I tried to center align the title of the paragraph. I've selected the first line(title) then Ctrl+E, the whole page moved to the middle. Is there a way which only the selected line aligned in the center, the rest remain at the left??? Thanks.

Comment: Give some space between title and the paragraph and try it

Comment: What's the formatting? Are you using styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure there's a line-break between the title and the paragraph, otherwise it's part of the paragraph. Put the cursor behind your title, press enter, then put your cursor anywhere in the title and press Ctrl+E. This way title and paragraph are separated, and aligned separately.